# I cannot boot Xubuntu. Can anybody help?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

[image: GParted screenshot]

I tried to dual boot Xubuntu and Elementary OS, I didn`t like Elementary and deleted it with Gparted, then the next time I tried to boot I got this message

```
Error no such partition
Entering rescue mode...
Grub Rescue
```

I had to boot from the cd to use the internet, somebody help me please I have no idea what to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Run Boot-repair and hopefully that will fix your issue!

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

Try [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)  it's pretty good at fixing this sort of problem.